# Super Basic Question: What to do when database schema and SQL expression are the same?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, command, syntax-error, database-schema

I'm a beginner with SQL, learning online. Forgive my ignorance!

Is there a best practice to use when working with databases that have headers/schema that are identical to SQL functions/expressions/commands?

For example, the database I'm working with has many CSV files with schema of **names**, **count**, and **gender**. So, of course, when I enter the SELECT arguments with the columns I want, it thinks I'm trying to calculate the count of occurrences of a value, and I get an error.

Here's the query I'm using that keeps getting a syntax error, line 3/12:

```
SELECT
  name,
  count AS 'total_count'
FROM
  `population_names.names_2014`
WHERE
  gender = 'M'
ORDER BY
  total_count DESC
LIMIT
  10
```

When I run it *without* the 'AS' alias, it works, but ONLY if I can make sure I select the 'count' predictive popup menu offer that is tagged with a little wrench in my query editor (BigQuery) so it doesn't read as a command.

[image: predictive menu SQL expression]

**But is there a more foolproof way around this?**

```
--This works if I use the little predictive menu while typing 'count'

SELECT
  name,
  count
FROM
  `population_names.names_2014`
WHERE
  gender = 'M'
ORDER BY
  count DESC
LIMIT
  10
```

Comment: simply put  - if you use keyword as a column name  - you should wrap it with back-ticks so system knows that this is not a keyword

Comment: `SELECT
  name,
   \`count\`
FROM
  \`population_names.names_2014\` `